# QGIS filling sinks for DEM using method by Wang and Liu

Tags: qgis

I am having an error when I run the `algorithm of Wang and Liu` for filling of sinks in the catchment area.

The error is following:

> "Load grid: C:/..(path)  failed"

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Several scenarios are possible here.

- Probably your QGIS has no read permission in that particular directory 
  because of UAC / missing admin privileges. Try executing as administrator.

---

- The algorithm you are using does not fit with the version of QGIS you are using. 
  Try using 2.18 Las Palmas, it's more stable then the current version 3.

For more answers you need to specify your question.
Version / Screenshot / Workflow.

Cheers